# Writing a Django migration that adds a unique field based off another field

Tags: python, django

I have a model `SessionCategory` with a unique field `name`. Certain pivotal instances of this model are referenced by `name`; the only problem is that `name` is also editable in our internal dashboard so that a user could inadvertently 'break' these references by changing the `name`.

To solve this, I'd like to create a new field `name_slug` which is a slugified version of `name`, also with a unique constraint. I've tried to do the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver



class SessionCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name_slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


@receiver(pre_save, sender=SessionCategory)
def create_name_slug(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.name_slug:
        instance.name_slug = slugify(instance.name)
```

where I've added the `name_slug` unique field. The problem is that if I try to `python manage.py makemigrations`, I get the following prompt:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'name_slug' to sessioncategory without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

I've come across a workflow at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields for writing migrations that create unique fields. In that example, the unique field is generated using the 'general' function `uuid.uuid4()`. In my case, however, I need access to the `name` of the specific instance, like I was hoping to obtain by connecting to the `pre_save` signal.

How can I create this migration and maintain the unique constraint?

Comment: I would suggest adding the field without `unique=True` first, then run a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), and then finally add the `unique=True` condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) feature will help you.
**Step1**. You have already a migration file **before adding `name_slug` field**. Then create a new migration file with, `name_slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True,null=True)`.The file will be like this
**`app_name/migrations/0003_some_name.py`**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('sample', '0006_sessioncategory'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='sessioncategory',
            name='name_slug',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

**Step2.** Add a custom migration scrip by using `RunPython` as below,

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.utils.text import slugify
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
SessionCategory = apps.get_model("sample", "SessionCategory")
for instance in SessionCategory.objects.all():
if not instance.name_slug:
instance.name_slug = slugify(instance.name)
instance.save()
def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    pass</b>

dependencies = [
    ('sample', '0006_sessioncategory'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='sessioncategory',
        name='name_slug',
        field=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=True),
    ),
    <b>migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func

                         )</b>
]</code></pre>
```

**Step 3.** do the migration by `python manage.py migrate`
That's it !

**Warning!**
**do not run** `python manage.py migrate` command on **step 1** (only makemigrations command)

**Note**
The migrations files are generated in my local system to reproduce the behaviour.It maybe different for you